# Intonation in interrogative sentence

Tags: pronunciation, intonation

I would like to know what kind of intonation the following sentences have:

> Does it hurt?
>
> Doesn't it hurt?

I pronounce both with the same rising intonation but my friend told me I was wrong.

Do both of the sentences have the same rising intonation?

Answer (score 2):

From [the Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/grammaire/grammaire-britannique/questions-yes-no-questions-are-you-feeling-cold?q=Negative+yes-no+questions) it can be seen that negative questions are yes-no questions and therefore they follow the rule of rising intonation for yes-no questions, which is the most of what there is to know but not all. The full rule is repeated below for convenience after a guide on forming negative yes-no questions.

> *Negative yes-no questions*
>
> We usually use negative yes-no questions to check or confirm something we believe or expect to be the case, or when we consider that something is the best thing to do:
>
> Isn’t that Pauline’s car? (I’m pretty sure that this is correct. I’m asking for confirmation.)
>
> Shouldn’t we be leaving? (I think that we should leave now.)
>
> We form negative yes-no questions with not. We usually use the contraction n’t. If we use not in its full form, the question sounds very formal:
>
> Isn’t that the oldest building on this street?
>
> Warning:
>   When using the full form not, the order auxiliary + subject (s) + not is more common than auxiliary + not + subject:
>
> [AUX][s]
>   Is that 
>   [not]
>   not the oldest building in this street? (formal) (preferred to [the very formal] Is not that the oldest building on this street?)
>
> We can use negative yes-no questions to make invitations, offers and complaints stronger:
>
> Won’t you stay for dinner? (invitation; stronger than Will you stay for dinner?)
>
> Wouldn’t you like another coffee? (offer; stronger than Would you like another coffee?)
>
> Can’t the manager do something about the noise? (complaint; stronger than Can the manager do something about the noise?)

> *Intonation and yes-no questions*
>
> The intonation of yes-no questions is normally either rising [ri↗sing arrow] or fall-rising [dow↘n u↗p arrow] intonation depending on the meaning. If we do not know the answer, we use rising intonation. If we more or less know the answer and are looking for confirmation, we use fall-rising intonation:
>
> Are you w↗arm enough?
>
> Did you once li↘ve in Ir↗eland? (I think the answer is yes.)
>
> We often use fall-rising intonation with yes-no questions when asking a number of questions together:
>
> A:
>   You’re living i↘n B↗ayswater? [Question 1]
>
> B:
>   Yeah. That’s right.
>
> A:
>   Are you rentin↘g you↗r house? [Question 2]
>
> B:
>   Yeah, we are.
>
> A:
>   Is it exp↘ensi↗ve? [Question 3]
>
> B:
>   It’s not very expensive for somewhere so near the city centre.